# extract multiple files with password

Tags: command-line, archive

I have about 200 files that i zipped long time a go in win. they are zipped with different extensions (zip, 7zip, rar,...) but the password to extract them is the same.

How do I extract all the files by inputting the password only once?

Comment: Use find with -exec.

Comment: how do i do that?

Answer (score 5):

The method to extract 1 file would be:

```
unzip -P password file
```

This is used to mark several files with different extensions: `*.{zip,7zip,rar}`

So I would start with ...

```
unzip -P password *.{zip,7zip,rar}
```

Mind though that this could error out on any of the files not being correct (damaged) or with the wrong password. Also: this is -insecure-: the password is typed in plain sight and someone checking the process list is also capable of seeing it. If that is a concern you should leave the "password" part and type it when asked.

No idea if it will ask for it every time though so you need to confirm this ;)

Comment: not working, getting errors "caution: filename not matched".         What should i do?

Comment: default unzip, as to Ubuntu 16.04, does not support extracting multiple files. Use something like `for zf in *.zip; do unzip -P *** $zf -d dstdir/; done`.

Comment: Note: `-d` is recommended when extracting multiple files to avoid mixing extracted files with original archives.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link out:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-unzipping-many-zip-files/

Basically you can use this code :

```
unzip '*.zip'
```

Comment: You missed the part of sentence after the word `…zipped…` ☺

Comment: -1 This won't work for all types of compressed files like the original poster asked.